# python: How does subprocess.check_output create it's calls?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mediainfo

I'm trying to read the duration of video files using mediainfo. This shell command works

```
mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Duration/String3%" file
```

and produces an output like

```
00:00:33.600
```

But when I try to run it in python with this line

```
subprocess.check_output(['mediainfo', '--Inform="Video;%Duration/String3%"', file])
```

the whole --Inform thing is ignored and I get the full mediainfo output instead.

Is there a way to see the command constructed by subprocess to see what's wrong?

Or can anybody just tell what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried putting it all in one argument? subprocess.check_output(['mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Duration/String3%"', file])

Comment: I did, but that does not work because subprocess can (correctly) not find the program "mediainfo --Inform=...".

Comment: I don't think you need the double quotes, try with `Inform=Video;%Duration/String3%`

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.

Comment: The two dashes are still necessary though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
subprocess.check_output(['mediainfo', '--Inform=Video;%Duration/String3%', file])
```

The `"` in your python string are likely passed on to `mediainfo`, which can't parse them and will ignore the option.

These kind of problems are often caused by shell commands requiring/swallowing various special characters. Quotes such as `"` are often removed by `bash` due to shell magic. In contrast, python does not require them for magic, and will thus replicate them the way you used them. Why would you use them if you wouldn't need them? (Well, d'uh, because bash makes you believe you need them).

For example, in bash I can do

```
$ dd of="foobar"
```

and it will write to a file named `foobar`, swallowing the quotes.

In python, if I do

```
subprocess.check_output(["dd", 'of="barfoo"', 'if=foobar'])
```

it will write to a file named `"barfoo"`, **keeping** the quotes.